# How to comment out some code fast with Eclipse JSP editor?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, editor, code-snippets

When I enter `<%--` Eclipse jsp editor enters `--%>` immediately near cursor. So I am to delete this text and enter it manually where I really need it. This automatic feature works more slowly than manual entry. How to educate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch off the default behaviour of closing the comment automatically you will find an option for this in `Window > Preferences` `Web > JSP Files > Editor > Typing` `Automatically close > JSP comments`.